# How to use Pandas to find 30 min average flows and then find max 30 min average flow per day?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have flow rate data per minute of each day.  I want to take average flow rates for every 30 minutes each day.  Then I want to find the maximum 30 minute average flow rate for each day.  Once I have the max 30 min average flow rate per day I would like to save them into an excel sheet displaying max average flow rate per day.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
peakflow= pd.read_csv('P:\Waste Water\Totalizer Data\Main DAF\July_1_17_July_20_17.xls.csv')
peakflow['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(peakflow.DateTime)
```

Here is a sample of my data frame called peakflow:

```
                     DateTime   Gallons
     0                     NaT  Average 
     1                     NaT      gpm 
     2     2017-07-01 00:00:00       743
     3     2017-07-01 00:01:00      1273
     4     2017-07-01 00:02:00      1256
     5     2017-07-01 00:03:00       723
     6     2017-07-01 00:04:00         0
     7     2017-07-01 00:05:00         0
     8     2017-07-01 00:06:00         0
     9     2017-07-01 00:07:00       455
     10    2017-07-01 00:08:00      1279
     11    2017-07-01 00:09:00      1258
     12    2017-07-01 00:10:00      1052
     13    2017-07-01 00:11:00         0
     14    2017-07-01 00:12:00         0
     15    2017-07-01 00:13:00         0
     16    2017-07-01 00:14:00       919
     17    2017-07-01 00:15:00      1271
     18    2017-07-01 00:16:00      1244
     19    2017-07-01 00:17:00       343
     20    2017-07-01 00:18:00         0
     21    2017-07-01 00:19:00         0
     22    2017-07-01 00:20:00         0
     23    2017-07-01 00:21:00      1248
     24    2017-07-01 00:22:00      1258
     25    2017-07-01 00:23:00       836
     26    2017-07-01 00:24:00         0
     27    2017-07-01 00:25:00         0
     28    2017-07-01 00:26:00       451
     29    2017-07-01 00:27:00      1284
```

I tried using the following code:

```
 df2 = peakflow.resample(rule = '30Min').mean()
```

To resample data frame peakflow and take an average every 30 min. then save it to a new data frame called df2 where I was going to use this code:

```
 df3 = df2.resample(rule = '1D').max()
```

To resample df2 every day and find dayle max valvues then save it to df3.

However my code did not work to create df2 and I got the following error:

```
TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, 
but got an instance of 'RangeIndex'
```

Do you guys got any ideas on what would work for this application or what went wrong with this code?  Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The dataframe that you try to resample must have a DateTime index.

```
peakflow.set_index('DateTime', inplace=True)  
peakflow.index = pd.to_datetime(peakflow.index)    
peakflow.resample(rule = '30Min').mean()
#               Gallons
#DateTime              
#2017-07-01  603.321429
df3 = df2.resample(rule = '1D').max()    
#               Gallons
#DateTime              
#2017-07-01  603.321429
```